# I cannot calculate a working AWS signature version 4 (hexadecimal string) for curl commands to work to test the REST API

Tags: python, rest, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I have never been able to get Rest APIs to completely work with AWS.  The error messages I have seen have been about the time not being correct or the command not being recognized (e.g., list-users).  I have verified the "version" was appropriate for the command with AWS's website documentation.

I am trying to use curl with Linux to list the users or instances in my AWS account.  I have a problem when I run it.  My current error, that I would like to focus on, is "request signatures calculated does not match the signature provided."  I went through the process of creating a signature carefully.  It wasn't that surprising that it did not work given the hours of trouble and the seemingly many potential pitfalls in the tedious task of creating a signature.

I used this link to generate the hexadecimal string for the signature:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python

I analyzed the output of the signatureKey using a modification of the Python code in the above link.  The result is not hexadecimal nor alphanumeric.  The result is a combination of special non-alphabet, non-numeric symbols and alphabet letters.  I tried to work around this problem by using import binascii and binascii.hexlify.  I was able to get a hexadecimal string from otherwise strictly adhering to the sample of Python code from the above link.  I tend to think my signatureKey is not right because of this binascii work that I had to do.  But what did I do wrong?  How is that Python code supposed to calculate a signature?

Alternatively, are there thorough directions not written by Amazon to create a signature key?  The process is not simple and seemingly error prone.  I could start over with creating a signature if someone cannot clearly tell me how to create a signature.  Amazon's forums have few postings related to this topic.  I'd prefer to create the signature with Python.  If someone recommends Ruby (an accessible language for me), I could try something like that.

Comment: *"The result is not hexadecimal nor alphanumeric"*  No, it isn't.  It isn't expected to be.  I suspect your problem is that you have found the right documentation but you need to slow down and read every sentence carefully until you are certain you have overlooked nothing.  For example, this statement is on the page you linked: *"Note that these are hex-encoded representations of the binary data; the key itself and the intermediate values should be in binary format."* The hex representation is for human readability/debugging.  The actual result should indeed **not** be hex or alphanumeric.

Comment: The result is used for the construction of a signature in an API call.  The code and documentation leaves out that a library binascii needs to be imported and then a hexlify function needs to be ran.  These, according to your comment, are crucial yet implied.  To me, it's inconsistent in the directions that are available with the code provided to leave out such a big step.  I'll continue troubleshooting this method. But I looked at intermediate steps and found digests were the same when I tested examples.  I'll also go back to the beginning and verify I have not overlooked something else.

Comment: No, hexify should not be needed.  The documentation *shows* the hex encoded versions of the keys, for purposes of illustration of what the actual bytes are, but the keys are not actually used in that form. You might find [the test suite](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html) useful.  It gives you sample requests and credentials and the results of some of the intermediate steps.

Comment: How do you do it without hexify?  The result is not a hexadecimal string on one line.  I downloaded the testsuite.zip. I see get-vanilla and post-vanilla files with file extensions such as .req, .creq, .sts, and authz. I see the content of these files. I do not know how to use them or apply them. Can you explain how to use this?

Comment: This is explained near the top of the page.  *"Each test group contains five files that you can use to validate each of the tasks described in [Signature Version 4 Signing Process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html). The following list describes the contents of each file."*  If that doesn't give you some direction, I am uncertain exactly what else can be done to assist you.